# DAX function to get specific value from dimension?

Tags: powerbi, dax, ssas, ssas-tabular

I have a model with **DimCustomer**, **DimSegment** and **FactRevenue**.

For most cases each customer is associated with a single segment.

There are a handful of Customers, that have two Segments… Therefore, in FactRevenue a few few cases of Customers have two Segments associated…

I want to “override” it and display 'current segment' only using FactRevenue (I don’t have a connection between DimCustomer and DimSegment)

Do I have any tools in DAX to achieve this?

Is it viable to have a mapped list of this exceptions and hardcode it somehow?

Comment: Your question isn't very clear.  What is "It" that is being overridden, what type of output are you looking for a small data sample might help.

Comment: What do you want to override? A value in a FactRevenue? You can override data in a source, not in dax. You can add a calculated column in any table with a new value of current dream segment according to your wish. Anyway, reprex is your friend.